# How can use apps for office to move an email to a shared mailbox?

Tags: office365, exchangewebservices, outlook-web-app, apps-for-office

How can I move an email from a users main mailbox to a shared mailbox using apps for office.  I know I can do this manually but i am creating an for owa/outlook that would be a button to move the item.  I have tried using ews but can only find the commands to move emails inside the users mailbox

for example :

```
'<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>' +
        '<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance"' +
        '               xmlns:m="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/messages"' +
        '               xmlns:t="http://schemas.microsoft.com/exchange/services/2006/types"' +
        '               xmlns:soap="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/">' +
        '  <soap:Header>' +
        '    <t:RequestServerVersion Version="Exchange2013" />' +
        '  </soap:Header>' +
        '  <soap:Body>' +
        '    <m:MoveItem>' +
        '      <m:ToFolderId>' +
        '        <t:DistinguishedFolderId Id="junkemail" />' +
        '      </m:ToFolderId>' +
        '      <m:ItemIds>' +
        '        <t:ItemId Id="' + id + '" ' +
        '                  ChangeKey="' + changeKey + '" />' +
        '      </m:ItemIds>' +
        '    </m:MoveItem>' +
        '  </soap:Body>' +
        '</soap:Envelope>';
```

Can I create a xml that would would do this?  Is there a way to do it using the EWS service reference.  I do not want to use import/export to do this.

The below code works as a Web Api if I could authenticate the user.  I do not want to make the user re-enter credentials for this.  However, this means I have the double hop authentication issue.   The above works because it sits on the users client side machine. Below, I have to host the web api and cannot pass the credentials from the web server to exchange.  A service account is also out of the question since I do not want an account that can access every users mailbox.

```
        ExchangeService service = new ExchangeService(ExchangeVersion.Exchange2013);
        service.Url = new Uri("Ews url");
        service.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultCredentials;
        //service.UseDefaultCredentials = true;

        // Create a new folder view, and pass in the maximum number of folders to return.
        FolderView view = new FolderView(5);
        // Create an extended property definition for the PR_REPLICA_LIST property.
        ExtendedPropertyDefinition PR_REPLICA_LIST = new ExtendedPropertyDefinition(0x6698, MapiPropertyType.Binary);

        view.PropertySet = new PropertySet(BasePropertySet.IdOnly, FolderSchema.DisplayName, PR_REPLICA_LIST);

        // get to the inbox folder of spam mailbox
        Mailbox SpamMailbox = new Mailbox("Smtp of other mailbox");
        FolderId SpamInbox = new FolderId(WellKnownFolderName.Inbox, SpamMailbox);

        Folder SpamFolder = Folder.Bind(service, SpamInbox);


        FindItemsResults<Item> findItems = service.FindItems(WellKnownFolderName.JunkEmail, new ItemView(10));
        foreach (Item item in findItems)
        {
            item.Load();
            ItemId ItemToMoveId = new ItemId(item.Id.UniqueId.ToString());
            Item ItemToMove = Item.Bind(service, ItemToMoveId);
            ItemToMove.Move(SpamFolder.Id);
            //item.Move(SpamFolder.Id);

        }
```

Comment: Dan, sorry for the late reply. Let me clarify your question a little bit. Are you saying the Managed API snippet below accomplishes your goals, and are wondering how to call that without having to re-authenticate the user?